# MIP Solver with Sensitivity option

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, simplex

I need a MIP Solver with Sensitivity Analysis option. So far i have found LPSolve IDE, and it has Sensitivity Analysis, but it is not supported for Mixed Integer Programming, only for the decimals.

Is there any MIP Solver able to do Sensitivity Analysis that you could recommend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, (standard) Sensitivity Analysis is not available for MIP models. Sometimes users fix the integer variables to their optimal values, resolve as an LP and then apply sensitivity analysis, but that leads to a somewhat different interpretation of the results.